# Can i customize PMD of my eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, pmd

We know that PMD is integrated with eclipse. And i want to customize it.
say suppose i want all variables to start with small letter
or say i want all method name to be more than 8 characters or so on.
is it possible to do that?

And does anyone know what PMD stands for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write new Rules with PMD.
In your case, new [XPath Rules](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/xpathruletutorial.html) would be adequate to quickly examine the AST (Abstract Syntax Tree) and perform the kind of detection you need.

[image]
<sub>(source: [sourceforge.net](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/images/designer_screenshot.png))</sub>

So you can declare [new ruleset](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/howtomakearuleset.html) and integrate them in [your eclipse](http://pmd-eclipse.sourceforge.net/) along with your PMD plugin.

---

Note: [PMD stands for many things](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/meaning.html) ;)

> We've been trying to find the meaning of the letters PMD - because frankly, we don't really know. We just think the letters sound good together.

- Pretty Much Done
- Project Mess Detector
- Project Monitoring Directives
- Project Meets Deadline
- Programming Mistake Detector
- Pounds Mistakes Dead
- PMD Meaning Discovery (recursion, hooray!)
- Programs of Mass Destruction
- Programming Meticulous coDe
- [A 'Chaotic Metal' rock band name](http://perso.wanadoo.fr/vachementbien/PMDnews.htm)

Comment: @gurukulki: I ma not sure what you mean by "full form", but if it is "what does P.M.D. stands for", you can see it here: http://pmd.sourceforge.net/meaning.html

Comment: Pretty Meaningless Description lol : in US they could probably patent the idea